# schedule periodic task at a fixed duration after previous one finished in java

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I wrote an application that runs a thread periodically using `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate` like this:

```
this.ExtractorTimer=new Timer();
this.ExtractorTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new java.util.TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
},0, 120000);
```

This runs next thread exactly after a specific time (for example 2 minutes) and if current thread was not finished, it runs next one just after current one finished.
I need that next thread run after a duration of time **after current thread finished**.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ScheduledExecutorService`'s [`scheduleWithFixedDelay`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method, which does exactly that. You may obtain an instance of such an executor service thanks to the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory class. This class is the replacement for Timer, which has some deficiencies.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `scheduleAtFixedRate` you could schedule the next execution after the task is completed:

```
public void initTimer() {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    scheduleTask(timer);
}


private void scheduleTask(final Timer timer) {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // perform task here

            scheduleTask(timer);
        }
    }, 120000);
}
```